# unable to merge large files in r

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I have run into a problem.

I have 10 large separate files, file type File without column headers, which are in total near 4GB which are require merging. I have been told they are text files and pipe delimited, so I added the file extension txt on each files, which I hope is not the problem. R Studio is crashing when I use the following code...

```
multmerge = function(mypath){
filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=F, sep   
= "|")})
Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y, all=T)}, datalist)}
mymergeddata = multmerge("C://FolderName//FolderName")
```

or when I try to do something like this...

```
temp1 <- read.csv(file="filename.txt", sep="|")
:
temp10 <- read.csv(file="filename.txt", sep="|")

SomeData = Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), list(temp1...,   
temp10))
```

I seeing errors such as

```
"Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit r" and 

"In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
 Reached total allocation of 8183Mb: see help(memory.size)"
```

Then I saw a someone asked a question on SO as I am writing this question, 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593177/manipulation-of-large-files-in-r), so I was wondering if SQL command can used in R Studio or SSMS to merge these large files? If they can how can it be merged to. If it can be done please can you advise me how to do this. I will looking around on the net.

If it can't then what is the best method to merge these rather large files. Can this be achieved in R Studio or is there open source?

I am working on a PC which has 64bit Windows with 8GB RAMS. I have included R and SQL Tags to see what options there are.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine doesn't have enough memory for your selected operations.

You have 10 files ~ 4GB in total.
When you merge the 10 files you create another object which is also about 4GB, putting you very close to your machine's limit.

Your operating system and R and whatever else you're running also consume RAM so it's no surprise you run out of RAM.

I'd suggest taking a stepwise approach if you don't have access to a bigger maching: 
- take the first two files and merge them.
- delete the file objects from R and keep only the merged one.
- load the third object and merge it with the earlier merger.
Repeat until done.

Comment: Clain - thanks for your reply. As I am attempting you advise I am getting the a warning message. Does it mean I it is not reading all the data. "Warning message: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : EOF within quoted string".

Comment: @ValdClain - I have attempted your idea and seems it does not read all the entries.