# How to export a datatable for each key?

Tags: r, export, data.table, fwrite

Let's consider the datatable :

```
> dt=data.table(v1=1:10, v2=c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)))
    v1 v2
 1:  1  a
 2:  2  a
 3:  3  a
 4:  4  a
 5:  5  a
 6:  6  b
 7:  7  b
 8:  8  b
 9:  9  b
10: 10  b
```

How would I do to export `dt` into as many files as there are `v2` naming the files after them ? Meaning one file named `a` containing `1 2 3 4 5` and one file named `b` containing `6 7 8 9 10`.

I tried : `dt[, fwrite(.(v1), v2), by=v2]` but to no avail.

Alternatively how would I export the dt into one single file formated as following :

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: You need to complete the question by showing what libraries you are using.  In particular, where are `fwrite` and `.`?

Comment: `fwrite` and `.` are both in data.table

Comment: `.` is alias for `list` function

Answer (score 2):

Taken from my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594237/2490497).

```
dt[, fwrite(.SD, paste0(.BY,".csv")), by=v2, .SDcols="v1"]
```

If you group by multiple columns, just wrap `.BY` with `paste(., collapse="_")`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Labels = unique(dt$v2)
for(lab in Labels) {
    FileName = paste("DT_", lab, ".csv", sep="")
    write.csv(dt[dt$v2 == lab, ],  FileName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also `split` the 'dt' into `list` based on the 'v2' and then use `fwrite`

```
lst <- split(dt, dt$v2)
invisible(lapply(names(lst), function(nm) fwrite(lst[[nm]], paste0("DT_", nm, ".csv"))))
```

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value, what does `lapply` give you that `for` does not?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg  I used `invisible` to not print it on the console.  My method is slightly better as I am `split`ting instead of `==`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg `lapply` give easier re-usable chunks of code, just be re-using functions passed to `lapply`, this is not possible with `for` loop

Comment: @jangorecki Noting stops you from defining and calling a function within the `for` loop.  `lapply` requires a function call, but it is optional with `for`.  Thus, `for` is more flexible.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg agree, but in `*appy` you don't even need to call a function, you can just supply it to `FUN` argument. This is nice abstraction on your code which loops won't provide.