# R Efficient way to split large amount of datasets from multiple files by level of factor using doParallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, bigdata, doparallel

I have a large number of files which I need to read into R, put them into a data frame and then split by a specific column ("pracid"). The computation will be executed on a cluster. My code is working with a smaller number of files, however the amount of data when using all files is too big for R.

Desired output: Separate files containing the datasets for each level of the factor "pracid". E.g. file1 contains all the data where pracid==1, file2 contains all the data where pracid==None, etc.

Error in data.table::rbindlist(dat): Total rows in the list is 3479242206 which is larger than the maximum number of rows, currently 21474833647.

I will also have to work in another directory with even more files. What would be the most efficient way to deal with this amount of data?

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse) 
library(broom)
library(dplyr) 
library(sqldf)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate) 
library(doParallel) 

procs = as.numeric(Sys.getenv("MOAB_PROCCOUNT"))
registerDoParallel(cores=procs)

files = list.files(path = paste0(data_dir, "Consultation"), pattern = "*.txt$", full.names = T)

dat = foreach(i = files) %dopar% read.delim(i)
dat = as.data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(dat))
dat = dat %>% distinct(consid, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% arrange(pracid)

write.table(dat, file = paste0(output_dir, "consultation.txt"), sep = "\t")

# Split by practice

dat.split = as.data.table(dat)
dat.split = split(dat.split, by = c("pracid"))

for (i in 1:length(dat.split)){
  write.table(dat.split[i], file=paste0(practice_dir, "Consultation/",
                                        names(dat.split)[i], ".txt"), sep = "\t",
              row.names=FALSE, col.names = colnames(dat.split[[1]]))
}
```

Files have this format:

```
patid    consid    pracid    staffid
50000082035    23408234    2002    12003
235235    234234    45666    209
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593177/manipulation-of-large-files-in-r/29594237#29594237

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much easier and faster in bash and awk than R:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /your/data/dir
# it's a better practice to make a separate outdir:
mkdir Consultation_bypracid
find Consultation -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 awk -F$'\t' '
BEGIN{RS="\r\n|\n|\r";ORS="\n"}
{
  # get column index of pracid column
  if(ci==""){
    header=$0
    for(ci=1;ci<=NF;ci++){
      if($ci=="pracid") break
    }
  }

  if(FNR>1){ # skip input file header row
    pracid = $ci
    if(outpath[pracid]==""){
      outpath[pracid] = "Consultation_bypracid/"pracid".txt"
      print header >> outpath[pracid]
    }
    print >> outpath[pracid]
  }
}'
```

On my system, a very large Google vm with a non-SSD disk, this processes about 1 GB of input data per minute. This task uses a lot of disk I/O and very little cpu, so parallelization won't help, and the speed of your disk will determine how fast this runs.

Outputs files to Consultation_bypracid named like [first pracid].txt...[last pracid].txt

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221337/discussion-on-answer-by-webb-r-efficient-way-to-split-large-amount-of-datasets-f).